# Latex ''missing number'' absurd error

Tags: errors, templates

I have a weird latex problem:

[image]

`missing number` : this does not make any sense. I have already found many answers on forums suggesting subfig/subcaption related solutions but neither work for me. The very strange thing is that this master thesis template compiled just fine before I reinstalled Win 10 with the SAME latex compiler (Miktex 2.9)
... please any help would be appreciated...

Best regards.

Here is the full template:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} % Your supervisor's name, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \supname
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \examname
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \degreename
\author{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\addresses{} % Your address, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \addressname

\subject{Biological Sciences} % Your subject area, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \subjectname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames
\university{\href{url}{University Name}} % Your university's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \univname
\department{\href{urlhere}{Department or School Name}} % Your department's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \deptname
\group{\href{url}{Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name and URL, this is used in the title page, print it elsewhere with \groupname
\faculty{\href{url}{Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name and URL, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \facname

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\vspace*{.06\textheight}
{\scshape\LARGE \univname\par}\vspace{1.5cm} % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle\par}\vspace{0.4cm} % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{johnsmithdotcom}{\authorname} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{urlhere}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\vfill

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfillment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

\vfill

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{declaration}
\addchaptertocentry{\authorshipname} % Add the declaration to the table of contents
\noindent I, \authorname, declare that this thesis titled, \enquote{\ttitle} and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
\item This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
\item Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
\item Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
\item Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
\item I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
\item Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
\end{itemize}

\noindent Signed:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature

\noindent Date:\\
\rule[0.5em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
\end{declaration}

\cleardoublepage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

\noindent\enquote{\itshape Thanks to my solid academic training, today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information, which is how I got a good job in journalism.}\bigbreak

\hfill Dave Barry

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname} % Add the abstract to the table of contents
The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{acknowledgements}
\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
The acknowledgments and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
\end{acknowledgements}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\listoftables % Prints the list of tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abbreviations}{ll} % Include a list of abbreviations (a table of two columns)

\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere\\
\textbf{WSF} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or\\

\end{abbreviations}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{constants}{lr@{${}={}$}l} % The list of physical constants is a three column table

% The \SI{}{} command is provided by the siunitx package, see its documentation for instructions on how to use it

Speed of Light & $c_{0}$ & \SI{2.99792458e8}{\meter\per\second} (exact)\\
%Constant Name & $Symbol$ & $Constant Value$ with units\\

\end{constants}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{symbols}{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)

$a$ & distance & \si{\meter} \\
$P$ & power & \si{\watt} (\si{\joule\per\second}) \\
%Symbol & Name & Unit \\

\addlinespace % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek

$\omega$ & angular frequency & \si{\radian} \\

\end{symbols}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter5} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\include{Appendices/AppendixA}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixB}
%\include{Appendices/AppendixC}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry the forum system is editing my message therefore it is not what I intended to post ... thanks to the super strict policies of this forum ....

Comment: Unfortunately,, the unformatted code is hard to read, but your error probably occurs before line 70.

Comment: oh thanks for your quick answer. Do you have a hint on what Latex means by a missing number ? To what it might be related ? (I will try to post the code better formatted )

Comment: Usually that error means that LaTeX expects you to insert a number anywhere and you didn't. Are you sure you used all commands in their intended syntax?

Comment: Where does `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` come from?

Comment: here is all the info:%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.x major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% This template is based on a template by:
% Steve Gunn (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)

Comment: the error won't be absurd, it is telling you that there is a missing number but you have not provided anything that would allow anyone to help. As the error is on line 70 make a copy of your docuument, delete everything after that, then delete any package you can delet while still makeing the error and make sure there are no `\input` to local files we don't have then replace the example above by the example that people can debug

Comment: Absurd in the sens that as mentioned: the file was compiling fine (before re-installing computer&latex) therefore I make the deduction -> not a syntax problem. Do you get it ? ;). (of course it has an origin, but clearly not syntax for the aforementioned reason)

Comment: yes I could send a dropbox link indeed: here it is : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuowRMxbsJjPioFD3CxHYG9tlg0Jzg

Comment: If you would have left the comment header of the mainfile where it belongs, people would have been able to find the template ithout asking back. Also, they would have known about copyright and licenses.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=102869#p102869)

Answer (score 2):

the class file that you are using in your Original_template.zip is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% Class File
% Version 1.5 (22/11/16)
```

and gives the error that you show. (no idea why: deep in some expl3 code processing the frontmatter:-)

The version of  the class at the latextemplates link that you gave originally is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% Class File
% Version 1.6 (27/8/17)
```

and runs without error on the `main.tex` in the template and on the text in your question.

Comment: this is the full template:http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/

Comment: ok I uploaded the template I used on: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuowRMxbsJjPioFD3CxHYG9tlg0Jzg

Comment: @MrCarlyle : ah I found something interesting here :http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=29970&p=101274&hilit=missing+number#p101274

Comment: @Machupicchu well the old one is failing in expl3 so it possibly worked with an old copy of that package, but rather than trying to find an old copy of that just going with the latest version might be easier (or not)

Comment: they seem to give a solution here : http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=29970&p=101274&hilit=missing+number#p101274
but I don t understand it yet.. (other people using this template have the same problem)

Comment: I wouldn't use the template to be honest.

Comment: @Machupicchu I have a question. How did you came here to TeX.stackexchange? LaTeX-templates.com and Sunils site both give another place to ask template related questions.

Comment: Well surely I will never use this template again... however unfortunately I used this damned template before (when it worked!) to write my whole 100+ page thesis ! and now I need to modify it... you can imagine my pain....because I m in a hurry now to submit it (with the same layout)...

Comment: OK problem solved by your aforementioned solution : simply remove crappy \thesistitle{} command and replace \ttitle by the hard coded title...I admit it was simple indeed.

I also had another problem with the degree symbol causing errors which is solved by:

\let\savedegree\degree
\let\degree\relax
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\degree\savedegree

Best regards,
and thanks for your patience